# what data is sent or received from apps installed on my android?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an android application which will display the user what data was sent from all apps and what data was received on all apps installed on the device.

I have searched but nothing came which could give me a start. Is there any encryption/decryption techniques used(Since i have no idea about the same).

It would be a privilege if i get to know where to start with this project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+capture+network+traffic

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking more about a background service running all the time, but that's really complicated if you don't have clear idea on how they works.

Start with this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html